# React server component cache function not caching result

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, next.js13, react-server-components

I have the following very simple function for getting data asynchronously. I am calling it from multiple server components in the same page, expecting it to be only called once thanks to the `cache` wrapper. However when loading a page it seems to be called multiple times (I see the console output logged multiple times). How can I get the cache to work?

```js
import { cache } from 'react'

export const getProductBySlug = cache(async ({slug}) => {
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient()
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('Product').select().eq('slug', slug).single()
    if (error)
        throw error
    return data
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React's built in cache performs a `shallow` compare between keys. For primitives (strings, numbers, booleans) that is fine, but for passing objects to cached functions it means there'll only be a cache hit if the same reference is passed.

Rewriting the function to accept a primitive (just the `slug` string) versus an object gets it to work as expected:

```js
import { cache } from 'react'

export const getProductBySlug = cache(async (slug) => {
    const supabase = createServerComponentClient()
    const { data, error } = await supabase.from('Product').select().eq('slug', slug).single()
    if (error)
        throw error
    return data
})
```

See caveat in the docs here: https://react.dev/reference/react/cache#memoized-function-still-runs

**Note**:
Spent a little while debugging this and couldn't find a ton of docs for it online, so I figured I'll share it here for future generations...